# Breakpoint Debugging forEach - JS

Tags: javascript, debugging, foreach, breakpoints

I'm trying to return the length of the last word in a string, I am struggling with debugging at the moment. The problem is with the forEach loop I hit a breakpoint that wont update the empty array.

```
function lengthOfLastWord(s) {
    
let spaces = [];
let space = ' ';
let spaceInd = s.indexOf(space);
while (spaceInd != -1) {
    spaces.push(spaceInd);
    spaceInd = s.indexOf(space, spaceInd + 1);
}

let nonSpaces = [];
let wordArray = [];
for(let i = 0; i<spaces.length; i++) {
    nonSpaces.push((spaces[i + 1] - spaces[i]) - 1);    
}

nonSpaces.forEach(function(number) {
    if (number >= 1) {
        wordArray.push(number);
    }
})

let words = wordArray[wordArray.length - 1];

if ((wordArray.length === 0)) {
    console.log(0);
} else {
    console.log(words);
}
};

lengthOfLastWord("this is my test string");
```

If I ignore the breakpoint I get the correct outcome, but I can't seem to figure out why the empty wordArray wont update.

(I'm sure there is an easier way to get the result using filters and mapping but i'm wondering if there is a simple fix to my current buggy code)

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your code seems to return the length of the second to last word, rather than the last. The problem does not lie in the forEach, rather it is in the way you're doing it. When you take the index of spaces in the string and calculate distance between each of them, this excludes the first and the last words, as there isn't a space at the very beginning and at the very end. As a result, the second to last word's length is logged rather than the very last.

The simple fix would be to add this line right after your `while` loop:

`spaces.push(s.length);`

This will make sure that the final word length will also be calculated in the following for loop.

As you are aware, there is a much simpler way to do this.

Here is one using `split`:

```
function lengthOfLastWord(string) {
    let split = string.trim().split(" ");
    return split[split.length - 1].length
}
```